# Final Dog Tag for We will all go together

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have completed nearly the entire quest except I can't find the last dog tag. The map pointer just shows me to the middle of town (I assume it is the middle) and I can't see any more ghouls in the city. I have gotten the tag from Edward, but I am still missing one. Any ideas how to finish the quest?

Comment: This wiki entry gives a pretty detailed run through of the mission: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/We_Will_All_Go_Together

Comment: I know the mission. What I am asking isn't "How do I complete this quest?" I'm asking "Has anyone else had a tag just go missing? If so did you find it? Or could anyone give any ideas as to why the tag is completely gone?" I have read the wiki, and have played the game 4 times through and this one time the final tag is gone.

Comment: That's why I didn't provide it as an answer. Cos it's not an answer in any way.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound ranty (is that a word?), I just thought I would clarify my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you've truly obtained Private Edwards' dog tags, then there's nothing to do but to carefully search each of the bodies to see if you've missed taking the tags off of one.

Otherwise, it's possible that you're encountering this bug, listed in the [Bugs section of Nukapedia's page on this quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/We_Will_All_Go_Together#Bugs):

> Occasionally, speaking with Edwards won't present any special dialogue options (intimidation, attacking Astor, etc.), and his dogtag will not be in the inventory if you kill him. The marker on the map will show the center of town, but no ghouls or corpses will be present making it impossible to complete this quest. PC users can use player.additem 0013fe77 1 to add a dogtag to your inventory, which can be presented to Astor for the reward. Alternatively, go back to the house where Private Edwards was and look around on the floor, you may sometimes find the 10th set of dogtags lying on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it shows me the objective in the middle of the town but it's not true. You have to search all the bodies of the ghouls you killed again. It takes me hours to finish this quest.